# GCP - create vm instance with two or more tags

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud

Using the code below to create VM with two tags, only the last one remains. Documentations says to use `--tags=TAG,[TAG,…]` but that does not work. Any help would be great. Thanks. I have tried the following, with several variations, but it does not work:

```
gcloud compute instances create vm-1 \
    --image-project windows-cloud \
    --image-family windows-2016 \
    --tags allowhttp \
    --tags allowprivaterdp \
    --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --boot-disk-size 77GB \
    --boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
    --network-interface '' \
    --network-interface subnet=ssubnet,private-network-ip=192.168.64.22
```

Tried to add multiple parms with and without commas, brackets, quotes and GCP does not like it. I don't want to add the tags as a separate step, `gcloud compute instances add-tags vm-b --zone us-east1-b --tags mytags`, since it appears this could be easily added at creation just don't have the right syntax it appears. Documentations says to use `--tags=TAG,[TAG,…]` but that does not work.

Expected to see two tags added to the VM, only the last one remains and other syntax changes dont allow the VM to be created

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-tags#--tags), you can add the tags in your command like so: `--tags=[TAG,…]` ; as seen in my example below.

`gcloud compute instances create vm-1 […] --tags allowhttp,allowprivaterdp`

Adding your tags like so should give you the outcome you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue. While go over the console and the command I found out that it works the the following:

```
gcloud beta compute instances create vm-1 \
    --image-project windows-cloud \
    --image-family windows-2016 \
    --tags allowhttp, allowprivaterdp \
    --machine-type n1-standard-1 \
    --boot-disk-size 77GB \
    --boot-disk-type pd-ssd \
    --network-interface '' \
    --network-interface subnet=ssubnet,private-network-ip=192.168.64.22
```

adding the beta works and if you remove beta it does not work.